# PHP imagecopy of any type to use in imagepng or equivalent

Tags: php, image, image-processing

I have a site where a user is able to upload a picture of their choice as their profile picture.

This profile picture can be uploaded as a .gif, .png, .jpg, etc, you know, the standards.

I then have a function that is supposed to generate a "poster" which contains all of these user profile images on it.

My code for this looks something like:

```
for each employee_image:
    $posx = get next x coordinate on poster
    $posy = get next y coordinate on poster
    $employee_image = imagecreatefrompng($image_path);
    $size = getimagesize($employee_image);
    imagecopy($poster_image, $employee_image, $posx, $posy, 0,0, $size[0], $size[1]);

imagepng($im, $poster);
```

After I copy each `$employee_image` onto my main poster image I complete and upload the image using.

`imagepng($im, $poster);`

The problem I am having is that this fails to work if I am putting `$employee_images`'s of a different type into the poster. For example, if my employee images are jpeg's then the `imagecopy` functon fails to properly get the image and it just results in a black image. I believe this is because when the poster is generated the types do not match because the poster is a png.

Does anybody know how I can solve this?

One solution I thought of is that I can just require my users to upload one type of image, such as only .jpg's or only .png's. But what if somebody has a .png and they just rename it to a .jpg, or vise versa, to get it to upload? Won't my poster generate a black image for this person's image because of it not being the right file type?

I would appreciate any help with this. Maybe there is an alternative function I can use or some sort of conversion to png before I `imagecopy` it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can get the imageType (3rd value of the returned array of `getimagesize()`) first, and then eighter do `imagecreatefromjpeg`, `...fromgif`, or `frompng`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library for work that does this.

See: http://www.geneticcoder.com/EasyImage/

Let's say you want a 3x3 poster with each profile image 100px wide (assuming they're squares):

```
$img1 = EasyImage::Create("/path/to/image1.png")->scale(100);
$img2 = EasyImage::Create("/path/to/image2.png")->scale(100);
$img3 = EasyImage::Create("/path/to/image3.png")->scale(100);
$row1 = $img1->concat($img2, EasyImage::HORIZ)->concat($img3, EasyImage::HORIZ);

$img4 = EasyImage::Create("/path/to/image4.png")->scale(100);
$img5 = EasyImage::Create("/path/to/image5.png")->scale(100);
$img6 = EasyImage::Create("/path/to/image6.png")->scale(100);
$row2 = $img4->concat($img5, EasyImage::HORIZ)->concat($img6, EasyImage::HORIZ);

$img7 = EasyImage::Create("/path/to/image7.png")->scale(100);
$img8 = EasyImage::Create("/path/to/image8.png")->scale(100);
$img9 = EasyImage::Create("/path/to/image9.png")->scale(100);
$row3 = $img7->concat($img8, EasyImage::HORIZ)->concat($img9, EasyImage::HORIZ);

$poster = $row1->concat($row2, EasyImage::BOTTOM)->concat($row3, EasyImage::BOTTOM);

// To send the image to the browser
echo $poster;

// To save to the server
$poster->save("path/to/save/to.png");
```

---

Here's a function

```
function makePoster($images, $rowWidth=3, $profileWidth=100){
    $rows = array();
    $row = null;
    $i = 0;
    foreach($images as $img){
        $i++;
        if(empty($row)){
            $row = EasyImage::Create($img)->scale($profileWidth);
        }else{
            $row->concat(EasyImage::Create($img)->scale($profileWidth), EasyImage::HORIZ);
        }
        if($i == $rowWidth){
            $rows[] = $row;
            $i = 0;
        }
    }
    $poster = array_shift($rows);
    foreach($rows as $row){
        $poster->concat($row, EasyImage::BOTTOM);
    }
    return $poster;
}

$poster = makePoster($ArrayOfImagePaths);

// To send the image to the browser
echo $poster;

// To save to the server
$poster->save("path/to/save/to.png");
```